# Different modes within org-mode

Tags: emacs, org-mode

How to define the mode at the headline level? I like to have data stored in my org-mode file and define the mode at headline-level rather than file-level.   So I like to have

```
* SQL Query (This should be in SQL-Mode)
Select * from sometable where some condition
* A Java Program ( This should be in Java-Mode)
public static void string..
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [source blocks](http://orgmode.org/manual/Working-With-Source-Code.html).  Something like:

```
* SQL Query (This should be in SQL-Mode)
#+BEGIN_SRC sql
Select * from sometable where some condition
#+END_SRC

* A Java Program ( This should be in Java-Mode)
#+BEGIN_SRC java
public static void string..
#+END_SRC
```

It's not quite as seamless as what you're asking for, but you can open the source block with `C-c '` and edit the code in a buffer with the right major mode.